# How could I url encode a list in python

Tags: python, url, urllib

Hi I am trying to url encode a list in python. This is the list: l = [['-3','3',['1004364']]]

```
l = [['-3','3',['1004364']]]
urllib.parse.urlencode(l)
```

When I try to encode this list I get the following error: TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object.

How can I encode this using urllib?

Comment: What would be the expected ouput?

Comment: I assume [ becomes %5B, ] becomes %5D and so on for the comma and apostrophe

Comment: You need to encode a *string* with those characters then. Encoding a list doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `urllib.parse.urlencode(str(l))`

Comment: From `help(urllib.parse.urlencode)`: "Encode a dict or sequence of two-element tuples into a URL query string." You can't encode the list you are passing as an argument.

Comment: What are you url encoding this for? this feels more like POST data than something you'd include in a url

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode()` is used to convert a mapping or sequence of tuples into a query string. [Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

In your case, it sounds like you want to replace special characters in a string. So first, you need to convert your list to a string. If it is a literal, like you show here, you can just add quotes around it. Or if it is a variable, you can call `str(l)`. Also, you should use `quote()` or `quote_plus()`:

```
quote(str(l))
```